# Sum same object in many list in Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python. How to sum the same object id in many list Python? I have sample data of this.

```
data = [
  [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'count': 10
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'count': 20
   },
  ],
  [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'count': 20
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'count': 30
   },
  ]
]
```

How to sum count of same id, so I can get:

```
data = [
 {
  'id': 1,
  'count': 30
 },
 {
  'id': 2,
  'count': 50
 },
]
```

Comment: This looks like a job for pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(sum(data, [])) # flatten the data
df = df.groupby('id').sum()
d = [{'id': index, 'count': row['count']} for index, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the optimal solution, but it works.

```
data = [
  [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'count': 10
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'count': 20
   },
  ],
  [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'count': 20
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'count': 30
   },
  ]
]
sumofdata = []
doneids = []
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        if j["id"] in doneids:
            for d in sumofdata:
                if d["id"] == j["id"]:
                    d["count"] += j["count"]
                    break
        else:
            doneids.append(j["id"])
            sumofdata.append(j)
print(sumofdata)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, at least I get the way to sum this data.